# Work with HTML and CSS in IntelliJ UE

Tags: html, css, eclipse, intellij-idea

I'm working on an application with a builtin jetty web-server and velocity templates.

While the application is running and I change some HTML statements inside Eclipse IDE, save the file and refresh the HTML page in my browser - I instantly see my changes.

However, with IntelliJ this is not possible. I always have to recompile my whole application to see my changes in the browser.

I've tried the LiveEdit plugin with a JS debug session and the JetBrains Chrome browser extension. Though the LiveEdit plugin is connected to the IDE I get always an "CONNECTION REFUSED" error. I've also tried some troubleshooting (changing IDE port etc.) - with the same error as result. I think there are some issues with the unrendered velocity templates here.

So my question is: Is there a way to have the same easy behavior while working with CSS and HTML files in IntelliJ like in Eclipse IDE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, finally got what I wanted. If anybody stumbles over the same issue, here's my solution:

In IntelliJ you have to `Make` the project or module over the IntelliJ build process to see your HTML and CSS changes in the browser.

To do it a little bit more comfortable you could record a macro in IntelliJ and bind the action to save a project combined with the make process to one shortcut.